# how to retain values after reboot using c programming

Tags: c, embedded-linux

Can any one help, The requirement is to retain the values of variables after rebooting the server.

Suppose i have multiple C programming files in a server for a single process, I want to hold some values before rebooting of the server, Once restart over i  would like to perform an action based on the last rebooted values(ie.., States).

I am not sure whether it will work or not but eager to know whether a global static
will holds the values of earlier states ....?

ex : static int earlier_status[10]

Note : My requirement is on Linux system to make it simpler i summarized for single process

Comment: How about storing the data in a file or database?

Comment: you can create a configuration file for your application and store/retrieve data from it whenever required.

Comment: We can store in a file or database/ flash memory and retrieve the information but it will lead to profiling i want to have other alternative approach..

Comment: C is a compiled programming language not a scripting language - the code that runs is a compiled binary not "C programming files".  Like any process, the runtime data is volatile.  Storing state in a file is the obvious solution - a memory-mapped file can even look like the persistent data you are asking for.  However if the reboot is uncontrolled, the data may not be consistent.

Comment: "_lead to profiling_"?  What does that mean?  There is no magic that can be performed that will make volatile memory persistent, or more importantly perhaps cause a process to be allocated the same memory on restart.  You have fundamental misunderstanding of how computers work rather then of C programming.

Answer (score 1):

Store your data in a [memory mapped file](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-system-programming/0596009585/ch04s03.html).  It will then behave and be accessed in your program as regular memory, but will be retained by the OS in the mapped file.  On restart, re-map the existing file and it will contain the last state.

Some caution will be required however - the state may be inconsistent if the reboot or termination interrupted mapped data access.  Some sort of validation of the data may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for retaining the updated values of variables after rebooting , it is necessory to store the values of variables in permanent memory as the temporary memory get erased when power off happens .
So for this you need to create the Configuration file( NOTE : Create in R+ mode because other modes will erase the data while creating the file if it is already exist) .  
- Create a file at starting of the execution in R+ mode .
- Write the variable in file which you need to retain , here you need to write the variable again and again where your program is modifying that variable , and here you need to take care of position of variables in the file .
- Use the fflush(file ptr); function to flush the file stream into file ( This is necessory to put data into hard drive for each variable modification , it will allows you to kill the process abnormally) .
- After reboot run the process(if your requirement is like , you need to start process with bootup then make it zombie ) and read and initialize the variables form the file and use in the program for further processing .
```